# JQuery datePicker not working for dynamically created input element

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to integrate the jquery datepicker to an input field which i am creating dynamically using script..

my script is like...

```
function getDate(id)
{
       $('.pop-up-link').show();
        $.ajax({
        url :   'gettartDate.jav',
        data    :   'Id='+id,
        success :   function(dateStr)
                        {
                             var htmlStr = 'Start Date : <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="startDateId" value="'+dateStr.StartDate+'"/>';
                             $(".pop-info").html(htmlString);
                             $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
                        }
}
```

I am calling this script when i need to edit the date in database and to add new entry to database. When i need to add new entry, im setting id as 0 and returning a blank string..

Now my problem. the datepicker works perfectly for edit functionality.. But when i add a new entry, the datepicker ui comes.. But the date is not updating to that input field. Again, when i put an alert to display selected date,i noticed that only date is changing.. The year and month is not changing, even when i change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be down to the fact you are dynamically adding the datepicker with the same ID's, i was having the same issue with dynamically created datepickers. if there was anyway you could take out the Id attr and use the Name attr it should work.

so you should have the following

```
var htmlStr = 'Start Date : <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="startDateId" value="'+dateStr.StartDate+'"/>';
```

Comment: Again i got another pblm.. That value is not getting when i used $('[name="startDateId"]').val();

Comment: Well if you have a few different datepickers on the page then your code `$('[name="startDateId"]').val();` will only get the first value. you need to add some context to where you are getting the date from by doing something like `$('[name="startDateId"]',$(".pop-info")).val();` but with out the full markup i am just making a guess.

Comment: no actually it was my mistake.. I had forgot to put a comment

Answer (score 1):

Try using the refresh method on .datepicker like so:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
```